# Is the below mentioned problem related to travelling salesman problem

Tags: graph

I came across this problem, and the first thing that comes to my mind is use TSP.

A person is visiting a new country which has several states. Each state has cities connected via bidirectional roads.
States are divided into cities such that for any two cities A and B,if it is possible to go from A to B  by a road and then return to A,A and B belong to the same state.

furthemore,everytime a person enters a new state, you need to pay a cost of 1 $.For travelling on roads that belong to same state there is no cost.

Given an image where cities are represented by colored dots and roads by straight lines, what is the minimum cost a person needs to pay so that he visits every city in every state.

For the image part, I think we can convert it to a graph by using some online library(recommendations on how to do this will be appreciated).

Also, if anyone could give me some ideas/suggestions on how to go about solving the problem, or if they have seen something similar, would be appreciated.

Enclosed are some images that illustrate the graph
[image: Graph image-1]
[image: Graph image-2]
[image: Graph image-3]

I also tried using opencv flood fill to compute the results as mentioned in the comments but it seems I am getting the incorrect result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread('graph1.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
M,N=img.shape
n_objects=0
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if img[i,j]==255:
            n_objects+=1
            cv2.floodFill(img,None,(j,i),n_objects)
print(n_objects)
```

for the first image,expected output is 6,but this returns 3 as the result.Any ideas what can be done to improve the result

Comment: Ignore that states have multiple cities, for starters. Treat a whole state as a single node. But then you don't have a "visit each state only once" clause, so this isn't exactly TSP after all.

Comment: And give an example image please. The specification doesn't state at all how interstate connections are defined, and what constraints they have.

Comment: I have added the images,would appreicate it if you could give me pointers on how to convert this image to a graph of form G(V,E).As for the constraints ,not much information about it was presented.

Comment: The cost is `number of states - 1`. You have to identify non-connected clusters.

Answer (score 0):

The entire prosa about cities etc. is just a red herring. It's not even a graph problem.

It's a basic flooding algorithm on the image which you need:

```
N = 0
While any pixel != White
    Flood with white from pixel
    N++
If N > 1
    Return N - 1
Else
    Return 0
```

Effectively you only count the number of connected regions which don't correspond to the background color.

Comment: When you say flood with white from pixel ,you are basically saying that pixel should be set to white right.Moreover,should I be considering the neighbourhood pixels also.

Comment: Yes, you should also be taking a look at the neighbouring pixels (including diagonals), and if they are not white yet you keep setting them to white recursively or iteratively. You do not set any pixels which are already white!

Comment: okay thanks.One final questionas i said before I have been given a image here,so is there any need to convert it in a graph of the form G(V,E).and if yes then are there any libraries or open source tools which  i can look into.

Comment: No, there is no need at all to convert it into a graph.

Comment: I was thinking about your code where you mentioned the following 
```
N=0
While any pixel!=white
 Flood with white pixels
 N++
```
If we did this on the first image where there is a straight line, then N will be incremented every time a non white pixel is set to 1  right.

I think the better approach is to find the no of connected components because the expected output for the three  images is  6,7 and 6.

Comment: sorry about the improper formatting,the  enter key on my keyboard is stuck.

Comment: If you flood correctly, then there wouldn't be any pixel left from that line. Flood doesn't mean "fill in a single pixel", but "all connected pixels".

Comment: Hi,I used the following code to do as you mentioned but it seems I am getting the incorrect result

Comment: You got the condition wrong when to fill. You should have done so for `if img[i,j]!=255`. And you shouldn't have flooded to `n_objects` (treated as a greyscale color), but to `255` instead.

Comment: You also need to reduce your input to pure black& white first if you try to use `cv2.floodFill` for this purpose. That function only floods areas which have the exact same color value, so the colored center causes you trouble.

Comment: ahh thanks.,also it seems that when I run on cpu,it is a bit slow,any way i can speed it up(I did feed it a black and white using opencv threshold method)

Comment: Hi,ext3h just wanted to thank you for the support and guidance offered.Was able to get consistent results.Just out of curiousity are there any other methods which can produce the same results?